# Set number of row for nested UITableView according to parent UITableVIew's section index

Tags: swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

I have a `UITableView` which is inside `UITableViewCell`. I set number of rows for both parent/child tableviews according to below array:

```
articlesArray = [articleTemplateStruct(articleName: "", clauses: [""], payments: [paymentStruct(amount: "", desc: "")]), articleTemplateStruct(articleName: "", clauses: ["", ""], payments: [paymentStruct(amount: "", desc: ""), paymentStruct(amount: "", desc: "")]) ]
```

For first tableView I set section:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if(tableView == articleTableView){
        return articlesArray.count
    }else{
       return 1
    }
}
```

And For second tableView i set numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(tableView == articleTableView){
        return 1
    }else if(tableView.tag == 10){
        return articlesArray[section].clauses.count
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}
```

Problem is here, in numberOfRowsInSection func when I want use section for table with tag 10, I need to access section of articleTableView section which tableview is inside it!
I do not know anyone can unsderstand the what I want or not!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if(tableView == articleTableView){
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContractTemplate", for: indexPath) as! ContractTemplateTableViewCell

    self.functions.enterValue(textfield: cell.articleTitle, phText: langc.article)

    cell.separatorInset = .zero


    cell.clauseTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContractTemplateSubjectsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContractTemplateSubjects")
    cell.paymentTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContractTemplatePaymentTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContractTemplatePayment")


    cell.clauseTableView.delegate = self
    cell.clauseTableView.dataSource = self
    cell.clauseTableView.reloadData()
    cell.clauseTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()


    cell.clauseTableView.sizeToFit()

    cell.clauseTableConst.constant = cell.clauseTableView.contentSize.height

    let artTableHeight = self.articleTableView.contentSize.height

    tableViewClause = cell.clauseTableView
    clauseTableFlag = true

    cell.paymentTableView.delegate = self
    cell.paymentTableView.dataSource = self
    cell.paymentTableView.reloadData()
    cell.paymentTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()


    cell.paymentTableConst.constant = cell.paymentTableView.contentSize.height


    articleTableConst.constant = artTableHeight + cell.clauseTableView.contentSize.height + cell.paymentTableView.contentSize.height


    containerHeightConst.constant = articleTableView.contentSize.height + 281

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    cell.add.tag = indexPath.section

    cell.add.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addArticle), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell

}else if(tableView.tag == 10){


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContractTemplateSubjects", for: indexPath) as! ContractTemplateSubjectsTableViewCell

    self.functions.textArea(textArea: cell.subjectDesc, text: self.langc.descriptionTxt)

    cell.tag = indexPath.section*1000 + indexPath.row
    cell.add.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addClause), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.separatorInset = .zero

    return cell
}
else{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContractTemplatePayment", for: indexPath) as! ContractTemplatePaymentTableViewCell

    cell.paymentTitle.textColor = titleColor

    cell.paymentTitle.text = self.langc.payment + " " + String(indexPath.row+1)

    self.functions.enterValue(textfield: cell.amount, phText: self.langc.amount)

    self.functions.enterValue(textfield: cell.shortText, phText: self.langc.shortText)

    cell.add.tag = indexPath.section*1000 + indexPath.row

    cell.add.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addPayment), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.separatorInset = .zero

    return cell
}
```

Comment: any chances you can put a screenshot to show how tableView's are listed and from which tableView you are trying to access.

Comment: @Lamiya check out my answer below if it works.

Comment: @Kamran: The problem is something else, see I want load number of rows according to array's index, which is nested array. For first tableview I want to set number sections according to articlesArray elements, and for second tableview I want set number of rows in section according to clauses array which is nested in articlesArray. for setting it I need to access the section index of first tableview to get 'clauses' nested array from articlesArray by index which is tableview section index.

Comment: And in simple words, in function of numberOfRowsInSection I want to know that the second tableview is in which cell of first tableview!

Comment: I hope you will be using a custom class for tableView cells. So you should introduce a indexPath variable for your first tableview cell and assign this variable in cellForRowAtIndex. So now as your second tableview is inside this cell so you have the indexPath to get the respective section.

Comment: @Kamran , can you please note down a sample code?

Comment: @Lamiya can you post the code for cell/tableView's for us to suggest a better solution.

Comment: @Kamran , I added it, please take a look on it!

Comment: @Lamiya This viewController class itself looks cumbersome as it has to handle `delegate/dataSource` for both parent and child. I thought to create indexPath in Cell classes. But i think u have to handle it in different way. I think you should create a custom `subclass` of `UITableView`. In that class you can add one member `var indexPath: IndexPath?`. Use this class for all the tableViews you have in this viewController. Then in `cellForRowAt`, you can assign indexPath as `cell.clauseTableView.indexPath = indexPath`, `cell.paymentTableView.indexPath = indexPath` so you access section anywhere.

Comment: This is one poor tableView design. Cells should perform their appearance inside their custom class, not inside cellForRowAt. Provide them with values, and let your code inside the custom cell class do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to introduce a better structure to allow each class to be single responsibility, for example the articleTableView's delegate methods will be within its parent class, and clausesTableView's delegate methods will be within cell, like so:

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let tableView = UITableView()

    var articlesArray = [
        ArticleTemplate(articleName: "", clauses: ["A1"], payments: [Payment(amount: "", desc: "")]),
        ArticleTemplate(articleName: "", clauses: ["B1", "B2"], payments: [Payment(amount: "", desc: ""), Payment(amount: "", desc: "")])
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.register(ArticleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ArtCellId")
        self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.articlesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArtCellId", for: indexPath) as! ArticleTableViewCell
        cell.setData(article: self.articlesArray[indexPath.section])
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ArticleTableViewCell.swift**

```
class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let clausesTableView = UITableView()
    let clausesTableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint
    var clauses: [String]!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        self.clausesTableViewHeight = clausesTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.setupUI()
        self.clausesTableViewHeight.isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        self.clauses = nil
        self.clausesTableView.dataSource = nil
        self.clausesTableView.delegate = nil
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        self.selectionStyle = .none

        self.clausesTableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.clausesTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellId")
        self.clausesTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(clausesTableView)
        self.clausesTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.clausesTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.clausesTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.clausesTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func setData(article: ArticleTemplate) {
        self.clauses = article.clauses
        self.clausesTableViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(44 * self.clauses.count)
        self.clausesTableView.delegate = self
        self.clausesTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.clauses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellId", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.clauses[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also changed some names of members/structs to follow naming conventions:

```
struct Payment {
    let amount: String
    let desc: String
}
struct ArticleTemplate {
    let articleName: String
    let clauses: [String]
    let payments: [Payment]
}
```

Comment: The problem is something else, see I want load number of rows according to array's index, which is nested array. For first tableview I want to set number sections according to articlesArray elements, and for second tableview I want set number of rows in section according to clauses array which is nested in articlesArray. for setting it I need to access the section index of first tableview to get 'clauses' nested array from articlesArray by index which is tableview section index.

Comment: @Lamiya see updated answer, try if you can implement the new design structure, it will help you not to bother with nested tableView to access parent tableView's section index, when you apply the `Single Responsibility` rule of S.O.L.I.D, see it helps with readability too